# What should Pi 3 CPU/GPU split be for command line boot to run MJPG-Stream

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, cpu, gpu, jessie-lite

The Raspberry Pi 3 - now has 1GB RAM, and older docs have always recommended 128M GPU split for most of the video streaming apps I've looked at - but a lot of them refer to 512M RAM limit in the older Pis.

I'm wondering what the GPU split should be for a `command line boot on Jessie Lite`, where the only function is to run [MJPG-Streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer)- for a live Pi Camera web feed over the LAN/WiLan?

There is no Graphics display, so I'm thinking CPU is more important than the GPU for video processing where no graphics are displayed on the HDMI monitor.

And would it help at all to assign a realtime priority to the process?

Final question - Instead of just looking at lags is there a way to physically compare numbers for different setups? Maybe some kind of log I could check to see if one method is working better than the other - maybe something that shows buffering or frame errors?

Comment: *"There is no Graphics display, so I'm thinking CPU is more important than the GPU for video processing where no graphics are displayed on the HDMI monitor.*" -> **No,** the GPU is still important.  It is used in the encoding and decoding of video formats and this includes the stream from the camera.  As to whether this will benefit from more than the 128 MB recommended for use of the camera I don't know.

Comment: @goldilocks Is the GPU also used for audio encoding/decoding? Or does the G imply graphics only?

Comment: The "G" in GPU is for "graphics", although what they are a lot about is *parallel vector processing*, which is an intensive activity in 3D graphics generation but not specific to it; hence big GPUs (the kind people pay hundreds of dollars to put into desktops, etc.) are also often used for computational tasks that have nothing to do with graphics (e.g., physics simulation, I believe, and probably you don't have to be a physicist to connect the some conceptual dots between "3D graphics" and simulating physics; also certain kinds of cryptography)...

Comment: ... However, I don't know how much of a role they play in audio processing generally or on the pi specifically.